# DFSR won't start replicating again after free space increased

Tags: windows, dfs-r

I have a situation here where one replicated folder in our DFS namespace stopped replicating because the disk was full. Ok, after 2 days we increased the disk space, but the replication is not working, the backlog is stuck in 3k files. Shouldnt it start replicating again after the incident? The event logs are in portuguese, sorry, but when it stopped I got one 5014 and then a 5012 in DFS Replication, basically saying it will stop replication and try again periodically (Error 9026: Invalid connection). I had to actually recreate the connections between the two members, replicate AD then it started replicating again. Is it normal?

Comment: I can't say whether it's normal or not, but I often have this problem too - when DFS-R stops replicating for any reason, I have a lot of trouble getting it replicating again, and often end up recreating the group to get it working.  Not really a big fan of DFS replication, for this reason.

Comment: Yes, I'm not so experienced with DFSR but I can see already that it has a weird behavior. I made a powershell script to monitor the backlog every 120sec with zabbix. Ive noticed that in the afternoon EVERY folder replication backlog starts increasing and actually dont replicate. Then at midnight (00:00) all of them starts replicating and the backlog goes to 0 in 15 min. The replication schedule is 24/7 full bandwidth. Oh well.